# Button Array and Switch Statement: ActionScript3

Tags: arrays, flash, switch-statement

I'm new to actionscript 3 (and this site) and I am having difficulty doing something that is probably very basic.  What I have is two movie clips on the stage that will act as buttons. I have named them btn1 and btn2. What I am trying to do is create an array of these "buttons" and add an Event Listener to each. When one button is clicked, you go to a particular frame. When the other is clicked you go to a different frame.  However, when I click btn1 I get "go to Frame 2" in the output window, which is incorrect.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

On frame 1 I have the following:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var buttons:Array = ["btn1","btn2"];


for (var i:int =0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    var buttonName:Object = buttons[i];
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClicked);
    trace(buttonName);
}

function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (buttonName)
    {
        case "btn1" :
            trace("go to frame 1");
            break;
        case "btn2" :
            trace("go to frame 2");
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MouseEvent.target` gives you the object that dispatched the event your dealing with in your event handler, with this is should be easy to identify it using the buttons id property (if you've set it) or via object comparison

Example using id

```
function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (event.target.id)
    {
        case btn1.id:
            //do something
            break;
        case btn2.id:
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            //do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Example Using object comparison

```
function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (event.target === btn1)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (event.target === btn2)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You have been extremely helpful.